# upgrade DC from 2008 to 2012 with exchange 2007 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2007, ms-office-communicator

currently we have server 2008 domain controller environment with exchange 2007 r2 & office communications server 2007 r2. we are planning to upgrade domain controller to 2012 r2 (both domain and functional level to 2012 r2). question is i want to make sure that exchange 2007 will still work after upgrade. i can retire office communications and use skype for business instead,. will it still work? what do i need to consider before doing this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you refer to the TechNet article here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx
expand "supported Active Directory Environments" you will see that Exchange 2007 with Windows 2012 R2 domain controllers is a supported platform.

There is nothing special to be done if the servers are fully patched. It is just the same as introducing replacement domain controllers. When you come to remove the old ones, be aware of what Exchange is using and prepared to reboot the Exchange server shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2013/09/17/exchange-support-for-windows-server-2012-r2/

"You will note that Windows Server 2012 R2 is currently only listed as a supported OS platform for Exchange 2013 SP1 onwards and Exchange 2016.  "

The note about the domain controllers is for authentication only, not for the purpose of operating system platform support.

Additionally, all support for Exchange 2007 ends on April 11, 2017, so it would be advisable to upgrade/move off of the product and not make any significant modifications such as this.